# collision with anchorpoints

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

So what ive done is i randomized anchorpoints and rotation speed for my CCSPRITE tiles, but this ruins my collision. how do i calculate the bounding box of the object while its spinning from rotation on an anchor point.

```
-(void)rotateTiles
{
    int aheadcount = [asteroids count];
    CCSprite *tileonPos[aheadcount];
    NSValue *tilecoord1;
    NSValue *spin;
    //NSLog(@"%d",aheadcount);
    for(int v=0; v<aheadcount; v++)
    {
        tilecoord1 = [self.asteroids objectAtIndex:v];
        spin = [self.spinvalues objectAtIndex:v];
        CGPoint spinint = [spin CGPointValue];

        CGPoint cgp = [tilecoord1 CGPointValue];
        tileonPos[v] = [bglayer tileAt:cgp];


        tileonPos[v].rotation+=spinint.x;
        tileonPos[v].anchorPoint=ccp(0,spinint.y);
    }

}
-(void)findTiles
{
    CGPoint tilecoord1;
    int tileGid1;

    for(int x = 0; x<30; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y<20; y++)
        {
            tilecoord1 = ccp(x+(480*currentlevel),y);
            tileGid1 = [bglayer tileGIDAt:tilecoord1];
            if(tileGid1 == 1)
            {
                int randomanchorx = ( (arc4random() % (5+5+1)) -5 );
                int randomspin = ( (arc4random() % (5+5+1)) -5 );

                [self.asteroids addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x,y)]];
                [self.spinvalues addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(randomspin,randomanchorx)]];
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the anchor point makes it tough because that anchor point can also be thought of as the basis of that sprite's position.

I'm assuming your asteroids aren't rectangles, so bounding box doesn't help much when trying to detect collision anyways.

If the asteroid is spinning on a random anchor point, it basically creates a collision area that is a circle around the anchor point, and the radius would be the longest distance from the anchor point to the edge of the asteroid. This can be calculated fairly easily, and you can just use `ccpDistance()` to calculate the distance from other objects. You would also want to add the radius of the object you are calculating a collision with to the calculation. Basically `if ( ccpDistance ( point1, point2 ) <= asteroid.radius + collisionObject.radius ) { // collide`.

To add complexity and realism to this calculation, you could use a radius that changes depending on the angle of the object you are trying to detect collision with. So if the object is at and angle of `M_PI_4` from the asteroid, you would calculate what the radius should be at that angle (according to the asteroids dimensions, anchor point, and rotation). This may be overkill depending on how fast the asteroids are spinning.

Another option might be to simplify your game, and always make the anchor point `ccp( .5, .5 )`. This way your radius would more likely be uniform on all sides of the spinning object. This also makes more sense from a physics standpoint, since I think objects only really naturally spin around their weighted center.